# How to join strings in Agda

Tags: string, join, agda

I am trying to join strings in the language agda. My code so far is

```
open import Common.IO
open import Common.String


f  : String  → String
f  x  =  x



main = putStrLn (f  "Hello, world!")
```

how can i join strings. In ruby it would be

```
open import Common.IO
open import Common.String

f  : String  → String
f  x  =  x + ' second string'

main = putStrLn (f  "Hello, world!")
```

How do I get agda to print out 'Hello, world! second string'?

I'd really appreciate working code

Answer (score 1):

Agda has a primitive called `primStringAppend` which is defined in the builtin module `Agda.Builtin.String`. So you can for example write the following:

```
open import Agda.Builtin.String renaming (primStringAppend to _+_)

f  : String  → String
f  x  =  x + " second string"
```

Depending on which library you're using, it may also contain a more convenient alias for `primStringAppend`.